# Run insert functions in PHP as transaction

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdo, transactional

I have a Model class which is in Model.php and i have two models like ModelOne and ModelTwo in ModelOne.php and ModelTwo.php. These models extend the base Model class. The model class extends a DatabaseConnector class which uses PDO to interact with database.

```
class ModelOne extends Model {
    public function storeX($params1) {
        $query = 'insert ...';
        return $this->insert($query, $params1);
    }
}

class ModelTwo extends Model {
    public function storeY($params2) {
        $query = 'insert ...';
        return $this->insert($query, $params2);
    }
}

class Model extends DatabaseConnector {/* not related to this question */}

class DatabaseConnector {
    private $_mysql;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_mysql = new PDO(...);
    }

    public function insert($query, $params = array()) {
        $sql_stmt = $this->_mysql->prepare($query);

        foreach($params as $i => $param) {
            $sql_stmt->bindValue(++$i, $param['value'], $param['type']);
        }

        $sql_stmt->execute();
        return $this->_mysql->lastInsertId();
    }
}
```

I am running two different functions in my model classes like this:

```
/* begin transaction */
$model1 = new ModelOne();
$anotherParam = $model1->storeX($params1);

$model2 = new ModelTwo();
$model2->storeY($params2, $anotherParam);
/* end transaction */
```

I want these two store functions (each one run "prepare", "bindValue" and "execute" from PDO) to run as transactions. What should i do? I prefer not to change my MVC structure.

Edit:
`$anotherParam` variable added.

Comment: if any other details is require for the answer please tell me.

Comment: Title: "transnationally" vs. Content: "transitionally" vs. Tag: "[transactional]" - I'm confused, please refine you post.

Comment: thanks @try-catch-finally, title edited.

Comment: You are still using 3 different words ("transnational", "transitional" and "transactional"). Do you want the 2 `storeX()` and `storeY()` methods to run in a single database transaction?

Comment: sorry @Nerdwood i meant transaction (auto correct problem). yes they are in single database, different tables.

Comment: Are you able to tell us what the models are representing? It might to understand the problem. What would the value of `$anotherParam` likely be?

Comment: $anotherParam is last inserted id after `storeX()`.

Comment: What do `storeX()` and `storeY()` return if an ID cannot be returned?

Comment: @RyanVincent if the `storeY()` fails i want `storeX()` to roll back.

Comment: @Nerdwood i wrote some code in classes. if this doesn't answer your question tell me to add some more details.

Comment: It looks like the 2 objects (`$model1` and `$model2`) would not be sharing a database connection, as each has its own `private $_mysql;` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Without changing your current `DatabaseConnector` and class inherintance

You could arrange a "transactional" fallback by using a couple of `try...catch` blocks if the `storeX()` and `storeY()` methods return `Exception` objects on failure:

```
try {
    $model1 = new ModelOne();
    $anotherParam = $model1->storeX($params1);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //First INSERT failed
    //Handle the issue and don't continue
    exit;
}

try {
    $model2 = new ModelTwo();
    $model2->storeY($params2, $anotherParam);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //Second INSERT failed
    //Roll back the first INSERT!
    $model1->removeX($anotherParam);
}
```

### Modifying how `DatabaseConnector` is used

It would be much nicer to use proper MySQL database-side transactions, but this would require you to have a **single database connection** that is shared between the various `ModelX` objects.

You should extend `DatabaseConnector` to handle transactions nicely (as suggested by @jayxhj), and this will suit your needs.

If you want/need all of your models to use the same instance of the `DatabaseConnector` class (which will allow you to use transactions from *within* your `ModelX` classes if you want), you could make your `DatabaseConnector` implement [the singleton pattern](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html#singleton).

I do not think that your `ModelX` classes should be extending the `DatabaseConnector` class - they don't seem to be more specific versions of the database connector. Rather, I think that the `ModelX` classes should just make use of the `DatabaseConnector` like this example:

**Wrapping calls in a transaction**

```
//Start transaction
$db = DatabaseConnector::getInstance();
$db->beginTransaction();

try
{
    //Do database work
    $model1 = new ModelOne();
    $anotherParam = $model1->storeX($params1);
    $model2 = new ModelTwo();
    $model2->storeY($params2, $anotherParam);

    //Commit the whole transaction
    $db->commit();    
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Roll back the whole transaction
    $db->rollback();
}
```

**Model class**

```
class Model {
    private $_mysql;

    public function __construct() {
        //Get "singleton" instance of the DatabaseConnector (shared between all Models)
        $this->_mysql = DatabaseConnector::getInstance();
    }
}
```

**DatabaseConnector class**

```
class DatabaseConnector extends Singleton {
    private $_mysql;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_mysql = new PDO(...);
    }

    public function beginTransaction() { 
        return $this->_mysql->beginTransaction();
    }

    public function commit() { 
        return $this->_mysql->commit();
    }

    public function rollback() { 
        return $this->_mysql->rollback();
    }
}
```

**Singleton class**

```
class Singleton
{
    /**
     * @var Singleton The reference to *Singleton* instance of this class
     */
    private static $instance;

    /**
     * Returns the *Singleton* instance of this class.
     *
     * @return Singleton The *Singleton* instance.
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (null === static::$instance) {
            static::$instance = new static();
        }

        return static::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Protected constructor to prevent creating a new instance of the
     * *Singleton* via the `new` operator from outside of this class.
     */
    protected function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Private clone method to prevent cloning of the instance of the
     * *Singleton* instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function __clone()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Private unserialize method to prevent unserializing of the *Singleton*
     * instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function __wakeup()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the `storeX()` passes and `storeY()` fails? how can i rollback the `storeX()`? i think you are missing the point.

Comment: This answer shows a method called `removeX()` being run on `$model1` in that particular case (when `storeX()` passes and `storeY()` fails). This is effectively manually "rolling back" the first part of the transaction that then needs to be undone. It will not reset the autoincrement ID, but it will work apart from that.

Comment: thats right, but this is a simplified example of my case, i have `storeX()`, `storeY()`, `storeZ()`, `storeT()`, ...

Comment: I have updated the answer to show the 2 different approaches that have been talked about. The singleton pattern example would only be needed if you are wanting the same database connection instance shared between all the `ModelX` classes (which might be a good idea for you).

Comment: That's great, hopefully that will make your code a bit nicer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

**@Nerdwood**'s answer meets your need.

There is another way

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(...);
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    $model1 = new ModelOne();
    $anotherParam = $model1->storeX($params1);
    $model2 = new ModelTwo();
    $model2->storeY($params2, $anotherParam);
    $pdo->commit();
} 
catch (Exception $e) {          
    $pdo->rollback();
}
```

but you should modify you DatabaseConnector class to offer an public database handler to support transaction.

Nerdwood's answer is to make it a transaction in language level,my answer is a way that database hanlers the transaction itself.

Additionally,you should check your database engine if it supports transaction.